# firefox and other apps not starting in livesession

Tags: firefox

I ran a live session DVD of 18.04.2 Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron 15 laptop to see if everything worked. I was not able to start Firefox or any other apps on the dock. I shut it down, ran another session with no change. I have been running 16.04 on a dell desktop flawlessly. Rather disappointed that the live session ran so poorly as I would like to remove Win 10 and go back to Ubuntu. I do not feel comfortable doing this seeing how the live session ran. Any idea why this could be happening? Not sure what else I could try.

thanks

Comment: DVDs are terribly slow compared to what we are used to nowadays. An Ubuntu live session that runs from a DVD will therefore perform quite terribly on anything that requires loading lots of data from the disk, like booting up and starting applications. If possible, try to flash the Ubuntu installer iso onto a faster USB drive instead and try again, that should make a significant difference to the DVD.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I also found my 16.04 iso and may try that to see if there is any difference.

Comment: I tried the usb method and all worked fine. The only issue is that I was trying to install synaptic and it would not work either through Ubuntu software or terminal. Maybe that would change afer actually installing the OS.

Comment: I think `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install synaptic` should work on the live system. If not, please post a new question and include the exact output of those commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue sounds like a disk I/O bottleneck. DVDs are terribly slow compared to what we are used to nowadays, especially if you have an older drive and/or the DVD is dirty or scratched and often requires multiple read attempts.

An Ubuntu live session that runs from a DVD will therefore perform quite terribly on anything that requires loading lots of data from the disk, like booting up and starting applications.

If possible, try to flash the Ubuntu installer iso onto a faster USB drive instead and try again, that should make a significant difference to the DVD.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer, as you confirmed my guess in your reply. If this really solved your question, please consider accepting it to mark your question as solved. Thanks.